# Getting result of Linq query after data binding a control without explicitly using .ToList() in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

Is it possible to get result of Linq query after data binding a control.

Example below:

```
GridView.DataSource = From c in Customers
GridView.DataBind()
```

I tried to get GridView.DataSource in the GridView's DataBound event but that contains the Database Query not the actual result.

How can I get the result?

Comment: Use the `.ToList()`  to execute the linq. And get the result.

Comment: Thanks for that. I failed to mention without actually calling the .ToList() method, because the GridView would have to do that when it binds, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this but adapt to your requirements...

```
Dim queryResults = (From c in dc.Customers).ToList

Gridview.Datasource = queryResults
Gridview.DataBind()
```

Comment: I know it can be done that way. I was actually trying to determine, when setting `Control.DataSource` as a query (not `query.ToList()`), how to get access to the result after a control is data bound.